# Pandas return column data as list without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

This is just an oversimplification but I have this large categorical data.

```
Name   Age Gender 
John    12 Male 
Ana     24 Female
Dave    16 Female
Cynthia 17 Non-Binary
Wayne   26 Male
Hebrew  29 Non-Binary
```

Suppose that it is assigned as `df` and I want it to return as a list with non-duplicate values:

```
'Male','Female','Non-Binary'
```

I tried it with this code, but this returns the gender with duplicates

```
list(df['Gender'])
```

How can I code it in pandas so that it can return values **without duplicates**?

Comment: Did you try using [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-series-drop-duplicates) or [`unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)?

Comment: Your values contains space, ex: "Male" and "Male ". Check my answer for fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these cases you have to remember that `df["Gender"]` is a Pandas Series so you could use [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-series-drop-duplicates) to retrieve another Pandas Series with the duplicated values removed or use [`.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas-series-unique) to retrieve a Numpy Array containing the unique values.

```
>> df["Gender"].drop_duplicates()
0         Male 
1        Female
3    Non-Binary
4          Male
Name: Gender, dtype: object

>> df["Gender"].unique()
['Male ' 'Female' 'Non-Binary' 'Male']
```